# Error al exportar celdas de contenido html con "DataTables"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

estoy utilizando el plugin DataTable para levantar unos datos en una Vista Parcial. Parte de la tabla viene pre cargada como html. El problema es que al exportar, me exporta algunos registros sin considerarlos como celdas.

[image]

El codigo que utilizo para cargar la vista parcial de la tabla (el valor '@item.inputCantidadXMaterial' contiene 5 tags "< td >" con contenidos label e input):

```
<table id="LibreriaMaterialGeneral" class="table-bordered display table-responsive" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">OCULTO ID MATERIAL POR LOCAL</th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1">ID MATERIAL</th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-2">NOMBRE MATERIAL</th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-2" colspan="5">CANTIDAD X UNIDADES</th>
        <th class="text-center">OCULTO ID UMEDIDA</th>
        <th class="text-center">OCULTO FACTOR DE CONVERSION</th>
        <th class="text-center">OCULTO UMEDIDA BASE</th>
        <th class="text-center">OCULTO NETO BASE</th>
        <th class="text-center">OCULTO MATINVPARCIAL</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.MaterialPorLocales)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">@item.txtIdMaterialPorLocal</td>
                <td>@item.txtIdMaterial</td>
                <td>@item.txtNombreMaterial</td>
                @item.inputCantidadXMaterial
                <td class="text-center">@item.txtIdUMedida</td>
                <td class="text-center">@item.txtFactor</td>
                <td class="text-center">@item.txtIdUMedidaBase</td>
                <td class="text-center">@item.txtValorNeto</td>
                <td class="text-center">@item.txtMatInvParcial</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
```

El resultado visual en la vista es: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución utilizando las funciones de Datatables disponibles en su librería y según su documentación [(ej de exportar a excel)](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel), agregue una funcion dentro de la opciones de exprotar. Con esto [recorro](https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-each-5297/) y obtengo los valores de la celda según su tipo de elemento html.

```
buttons: [
     $.extend(true, {}, {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'EXCEL',
                title: 'TITULO ARCHIVO',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                    format: {
                        body: function (data, row, column, node) {

                            if (column >= 2) {

                                var html = $.parseHTML(data);
                                var celda = "";

                                $.each(html, function (i, elemento) {
                                    if (elemento.innerHTML != 'N/A') {
                                        if (i == 1 || i == 2) {
                                            if (elemento.innerHTML != "")
                                                celda = celda + elemento.innerHTML;
                                        }
                                        if (i == 3) {
                                            celda = celda + elemento.value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                return data = celda;

                            } else {
                                return data;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]